# Unparseable date +01:00 groovy

Tags: date, groovy, unparseable

How to parse this date format?
2019-05-14T15:07:19.000+01:00

I have used "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" but I am getting an unparseable date error.

have also tried these:
yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX

but these also have unparseable date error.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Below is the error seen.
Error executing data process; Caused by: Error executing data process; Caused by: Unparseable date: "2019-05-14T15:07:19.000+01:00" (in groovy2 script); Caused by: Unparseable date: "2019-05-14T15:07:19.000+01:00"

Comment: What version of the jdk are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on top of Java 8, you can use `ZonedDateTime` to parse this by simply:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-05-14T15:07:19.000+01:00")
```

Comment: Since the string contains an offset (+01:00) and no time zone (like Europe/London, for example), it’s even better to use `OffsetDateTime` than `ZonedDateTime`.